# Not all layers of tmap rendering

Tags: r

I have three 'layers' I would like to render on a map.

1) County-level estimates for various ACS 5-year variables (acquired through the `tidycensus` package) (in pseudocode below: `data`)

2) State boundaries, generated by aggregating 1) to the State-level (in pseudocode below: `states`)

3) The Great Lakes (acquired from [here](http://gis-michigan.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/6031c4fb8cac48649f2e0a98999d1248_0?geometry=131.942%2C-4.926%2C137.567%2C75.495)) (in pseudocode below: `lakes`)

When I map 2) and 3) using the following:

```
  tm_shape(states) +
    tm_borders(col = "black", 
               alpha = 0.5) +
  tm_shape(lakes) +
    tm_fill("skyblue")
```

...it properly renders the state outlines and lakes. However, when I render 1), 2), and 3) using the following...

```
tm_shape(data) +
    tm_polygons("variable") + 
    tm_legend(legend.position = c("right", "bottom")) +
    tm_layout(title = "var name",
              title.size = 1.1,
              title.position = c("center", "top"),
              inner.margins = c(0.06, 0.10, 0.10, 0.08)) +
 tm_shape(states) +
    tm_borders(col = "black", 
               alpha = 0.5) +
 tm_shape(lakes) +
    tm_fill("skyblue")
```

...the lakes are always omitted, no matter the ordering. Has anyone encountered this before? Am I missing something about the ordering of 'layers' in tmap?

Comment: Is there anyway you can make a fully reproducible example using data that doesn't need an API key?

Comment: Sure, will give it a shot - one sec

Comment: If I use `data=county_laea` and `states=state_laea` and `data$variable=1:nrow(data)` and read `lakes` from the shapefile and then transform it to the CRS of `data` then your code works for me.

Comment: Apologies for not following up - got caught up at work. I will try this tomorrow and get back to you ASAP! Will say that I transformed lakes to the appropriate crs but that had no effect on my results. Didn't save it and reload, though...

Comment: @Spacedman you have saved the day yet again...that's so interesting and yet frustrating! So to recap, I have changed my order of layers to 1. county_laea, 2. ACS api query (from original post), 3. lakes (from original post), and 4. state boundaries (from original post). What do you think was causing this behavior?

Comment: Sorry I don't follow... can you edit your Q and maybe show my reproducible code and say if that works and then your code and how that doesn't work?